# Set pointer of array to specific element of array inside a function in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and want to set the pointer to a aspecific element in it (inside a function)

```
function arrowlink($side){
        reset($Arrowdata);
        $currentelement = '$_GET[food]';
        if ($side == 'left') {
            while (current($Arrowdata) !== $currentelement) {
            next($Arrowdata);
            }
    }
```

$Arrowdata looks like this:
`Array ( [0] => Apricots [1] => Asparagus [2] => Broccoli, raw [3] => Cabbage [4] => Carrots)`

$_GET[food] is the name of a food

I always get this error:  Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ...
and  Warning: current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ...

it ends in and endless loop.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `$Arrowdata` doesn't seem to have a value. Can you share more code?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have `$Arrowdata` defined outside the function which means `$Arrowdata` doesn't exist in the function scope. You could solve it doing this:

```
$Arrowdata= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$side = 'left';
arrowlink($side, $Arrowdata);
function arrowlink($side, $Arrowdata){
        reset($Arrowdata);
        $currentelement = '$_GET[food]';
        if ($side == 'left') {
            while (current($Arrowdata) !== $currentelement) {
            next($Arrowdata);
        }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `$Arrowdata` be passed by reference? Otherwise when entering a function a copy of this array is created and after function call the original array will remain untouched.
What is more - your code assumes always finding current element, if no `$currentelement` is present in an array - it will run forever and little bit more (infinite while loop). Fix it, please.

Answer (score 0):

you're not defining an array. in your code:

```
function arrowlink($side){
        reset($Arrowdata);
        $currentelement = '$_GET[food]';
        if ($side == 'left') {
            while (current($Arrowdata) !== $currentelement) {
            next($Arrowdata);
            }
    }
```

$ArrowData isn't an array unless you define 
$ArrowData = array(); as an array. You also want to populate the $ArrowData field. It's not 
structured the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is defined before the function and you want to access it you should use [the `global` keyword](https://www.php.net/language.variables.scope.php). Also you should verify the value returned by the [`next` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) (it returns `FALSE` when no more elements in the array).

```
function arrowlink($side){
    global $Arrowdata;
    reset($Arrowdata);
    $currentelement = $_GET[food]; // $_GET[food] is already a string !
    if ($side == 'left') {
        while (current($Arrowdata) !== $currentelement){
            if(next($Arrowdata) === FALSE)
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in my opinion noone has still fixed their answer to work properly, here's mine. It fixes multiple mistakes that you made:

1. You do not pass an array to the function - it won't work without it
2. **You have to pass this array to the function by reference**, otherwise function will not change anything in the original array. Using `global` keyword instead is neither a good nor preferred idea I'd say.
3. Allowed $sides should be provided in the function, to prevent doing anything accidentally
4. It's generally not a good design to use `$_GET` inside functions - pass the desired $_GET value as an argument

Here's the code:

```
$Arrowdata= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$side = 'left';
arrowlink($Arrowdata, $side, $_GET['food']);

//notice the passing by reference
function arrowlink(& $Arrowdata, $side, $currentelement){
   //put allowed sides here
   $allowedSides = array('left');
   //only allowed sides change arrays, others do not do anything
   if (!in_array($side, $allowedSides)) return;

   reset($Arrowdata);
   //$currentelement = '$_GET[food]';  // it is now passed to the function
   if ($side == 'left') {
      while (current($Arrowdata) !== $currentelement) {
         if (FALSE === next($Arrowdata)) {
            break;  //break if no next elements are there
         }
      }
   }
}
```